# Hpricot - undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hpricot

I recently did a bundle update which ended up breaking a lot of stuff. One of the things I haven't been able to resolve is with hpricot which I use to format text.

Any hpricot users ever get this to_sym for nilClass error before? thanks

**Error:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass):
config/initializers/hpricot_text_transform.rb:11:in `text_transform!'
```

**config/initializers/hpricot_text_transform.rb**

```
# By Henrik Nyh <http://henrik.nyh.se> 2007-03-28.
# Based on http://vemod.net/code/hpricot_goodies/hpricot_text_gsub.rb.
# Licensed under the same terms as Ruby.

require "rubygems"
require "hpricot"

module HpricotTextTransform
  module NodeWithChildrenExtension
    def text_transform!(options={}, &block)
      return if defined?(name) and Array(options[:except]).include?(name.to_sym)
      children.each { |c| c.text_transform!(options, &block) }
    end
  end

  module TextNodeExtension
    def text_transform!(options={}, &block)
      content.replace yield(content)
    end
  end

  module BogusETagExtension
    def text_transform!(options={}, &block)
    end
  end
end

Hpricot::Doc.send(:include,  HpricotTextTransform::NodeWithChildrenExtension)
Hpricot::Elem.send(:include, HpricotTextTransform::NodeWithChildrenExtension)
Hpricot::BogusETag.send(:include, HpricotTextTransform::BogusETagExtension)
Hpricot::Text.send(:include, HpricotTextTransform::TextNodeExtension)
```

Comment: `name` is nil. where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
return if defined?(name) and Array(options[:except]).include?(name.to_sym)
```

with

```
return if defined?(name) and !(name.nil?) and Array(options[:except]).include?(name.to_sym)
```